# How does system fill MIB entries with Read-Only Access?

Tags: network-protocols, snmp

For managing the system configuration, we use MIB Management Systems in some form or the other, which may be C-structure based or Yang Module for data modeling. Now there are entries in the MIB which are marked as read-only, or not accessible for the manager i.e. Northbound Interfaces. The operational data is often kept in such entries, like system up-time etc.

So, is the filling of data by the Device itself in these fields implementation specific or does the device also use GET/SET/TEST type of mechanism to write to these MIB leafs?

Answer (score 1):

When you are defining MIB with ASN.1 ,

> MAX-ACCESS

clause will be

> READ-ONLY

for that particular data. So it makes snmp-set queries to fail on that particular Object Identifiers (OIDs) because the agent does not allow any values to be set for them. Other possible values for MAX-ACCESS are READ-WRITE, RIGHT-CREATE, WRITE-ONLY, NOT-ACCESSIBLE and ACCESSIBLE-FOR_NOTIFY.  Take a look at the online edition of [Essential SNMP](http://oreilly.com/catalog/esnmp/chapter/ch02.html) for information.

Comment: That is exactly what I am talking about. They are not available for SET operations from the manager (Northbound Interfaces).

I am asking how does the device (Southbound Interface) access them to write in the operational data.

Comment: Why does the South Bound or device itself has to use that SNMP interface at all? NBI actually defines the SNMP interface for the upper layers to communicate. There is nothing called access restriction for the data available locally. Also your the OID is just a pointer to the data, it is not the data resides at the point you query.

Comment: The online link to Essential SNMP is now dead. I found it at http://it-ebooks.info/book/367/